# SignalR C# Programs Causing Numerous Error: 28504, Severity 11, State 1 Errors

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-signalr

I have multiple C# SignalR programs employing SQL Notifications.  However, recently, the log file is beginning to fill up with the same errors:

First:

> The query notification dialog on conversation handle '{73D05173-6BB5-EE11-B026-A8A159C669D8}.' closed due to the following error: '`-8490`Cannot find the remote service 'SqlQueryNotificationService-96b6fb3d-db9b-45dd-b0de-e8748f4107b6' because it does not exist.'.

Second:

> Error: 28504, Severity 11, State 1 Errors

Third:

> Service Broker needs to access the master key in the database 'myDb'. Error code:32. The master key has to exist and the service master key encryption is required.
> Blockquote

I recently tested a new Windows app using SQL Notifications, but needed to shut it down due the log file growing too fast.  I've done quite a few searches on this, but can't seem to find a definitive fix.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using [`SqlNotificationRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqlnotificationrequest)? The errors suggest you're using [`SqlDependency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency). See also, [Stopping SqlDependency gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440948/stopping-sqldependency-gracefully) and the linked blog posts.

Comment: The last error relates to having a [database master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)(DMK) in your user database that is protected with a password but not the service master key. Do you know what the DMK password is? If so, you can issue an `open master key` statement followed by `alter master key add encryption by service master key;`.

Comment: Apologies.  I mis-spoke.  It is SQL Dependency.  Regarding the DMK, I was unaware this database had one.